# Слишком много запятых?..

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Сегодня прочитала объявление, в котором были такие предложения:
*"На прошедшем родительском собрании, было решено собрать по пятьсот рублей.
Деньги можно передать Ивановой, либо учителю.
Оставшиеся неизрасходованными денежные средства, перенесены на следующий год.
Эти средства, так же учитывались при расчете расходов."*
На мой взгляд, все запятые лишние, к тому же "так же" в последнем предложении пишется слитно. Решила проверить в текстовом редакторе Word, но результат проверки не показал ошибок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему? Или я неправа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю русский язык, *"на ... собрании"* - обычное обстоятельство - не выделяется запятой, *"Ивановой, либо учителю"* - одиночный разделительный союз ЛИБО - не выделяется запятой, *"оставшиеся неизрасходованными денежные средства перенесены..."* - вообще никаких осложнений, *"средства учитывались"* тоже нет осложнений, *"так же"* - слитно